# APEX Trigger error when update List has no rows for assignment

Tags: apex, trigger

I want to make a trigger to update my custom object `Term_of_Payment__c` amount field.

```
Term of Payment Amount = Opportunity Amount / Interval (picklist type on opportunity)
```

This is what i`ve tried so far.. but everytime i update the term of payment record.

> Error : List has no rows for assignment to SObject:

```
trigger updateAmount on Term_of_Payment__c (before insert, before update) {
for (Term_of_Payment__c top : trigger.new){
    List <Term_of_Payment__c> topList = new List <Term_of_Payment__c>();
    List <Opportunity> oppList = new List <Opportunity>();
    Id oppId = [SELECT Id, Opportunity__c FROM Term_of_Payment__c WHERE Id = :top.Id].Opportunity__c; 

        for (Opportunity opp : [SELECT Id, Interval__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :oppId]){
            AggregateResult Amount = [SELECT Id, SUM(Amount) tAmount FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :oppId GROUP BY Id];
            top.Amount__c = (Decimal) Amount.get('tAmount') / Decimal.ValueOf(opp.Interval__c);
        }

}
}
```

Comment: there`s 1 record in term of payment object before I create the trigger.. when i update that record, the amount filled exactly what i want.. but i cant create a new record now  because of the error

Comment: How  `Opportunity__c ` field will populate on `Term_of_Payment__c ` object? You will not get Record ID for `Term_of_Payment__c ` in before insert event.  Thus you can't fetch same record in before insert event, and you are getting error. Best Practise Never write SOQL query inside for loop.

Comment: Positive this is a duplicate. A little effort on the OPs part and they would have an answer. If I was not on mobile I would post link. OP do a search on the error message

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger should be as follows:

```
trigger updateAmount on Term_of_Payment__c (before insert, before update) {

    Map<Id, Term_of_Payment__c> mapOppVSTop = new Map<Id, Term_of_Payment__c>();
    for (Term_of_Payment__c top : trigger.new){
        mapOppVSTop.put(top.Opportunity__c, top);
    }

    for(AggregateResult aggResults : [SELECT Id, Interval__c, SUM(Amount) oppAmount FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :mapOppVSTop.keySet() GROUP BY Id, Interval__c]){
        if(mapOppVSTop.containsKey(aggResults.Id) && aggResults.get('oppAmount')!=null && aggResults.get('Interval__c')!=null){
            mapOppVSTop.get(aggResults.Id).Amount__c = (Decimal)aggResults.get('oppAmount') / Decimal.ValueOf((String)aggResults.get('Interval__c'));
        }
    }
}
```

You may adjust the code accordingly.